# Missing message body reader in dropwizard 0.7 resource tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, dropwizard

I am trying to migrate an old dropwizard-0.6 project to dropwizard-0.7 and I get the famous message body reader error in my resource unit tests.

```
ERROR [2014-05-02 09:52:59,873] com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse: A message body reader for Java class foo.Bar, and Java type class foo.Bar, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found
ERROR [2014-05-02 09:52:59,876] com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse: The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
application/octet-stream ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
```

I used to add `ViewMessageBodyWriter` with old dropwizard-0.6 `ResourceTest`s like this:

```
@Override
protected void setUpResources() throws Exception {
    ...
    addProvider(ViewMessageBodyWriter.class);
    ...
}
```

I can't introduce the old `ViewMessageBodyWriter` because it does not have a zero-arg constructor any more:

```
public class BarResourceTest extends AuthenticatedResourceTest {
    static BarController barController = mock(BarController.class);

    @Mock
    Page<Bar> page;

    @ClassRule
    public static ResourceTestRule resource = ResourceTestRule.builder().addProvider(ViewMessageBodyWriter.class)
        .addResource(new BarResource(barController)).build();

    private Bar bar;

}
```

Can someone please help with resource tests in dropwizard-0.7?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
@Provider
@Produces(application/octet-stream)
public class YourTestBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<foo.Bar> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(foo.BarBodyWriter.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return foo.Bar.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(
        Bar t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(
        Bar t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        String message = t.someMethod()
        entityStream.write(message.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
        LOG.info(message);
    }

}
```

Add in your app run():

```
// Serializer
environment.jersey().register(new YourTestBodyWriter ());
```

Thats the normal way in your application. For junit tests perhaps this works (not tested by me!):

```
   @ClassRule
    public static ResourceTestRule resource = ResourceTestRule.builder().addProvider(ViewMessageBodyWriter.class)
        .addResource(new BarResource(barController)).addProvider(new YourTestBodyWriter()).build();
```